# Screenrecorder for Linux that catches specific windows

Tags: ubuntu, screen-recording

I would like to record a specific window together with audio from my mic. I work with Ubuntu.

I am thinking of a similar functionality as recording via Zoom, except that the recording is saved on my harddrive. Think of somebody recording a presentation.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) that has many options for source selection.